# Router + Clean-URL's: Load new site - requiere() works but header() works not

Tags: php, header, require, router, clean-urls

In my webprojekt i use Routing + Clean URL's.

My htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

My index.php:

```
<?php

    $projectname = "/FB-Clone2/";
    $requestAction = substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], strlen($projectname), strlen($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']));

    $requestAction = explode("/", $requestAction);

    $root = str_replace('\\', '/', dirname(__FILE__)).'/';
    $GLOBALS['root'] = $root;

    switch ($requestAction[0]) {

        case 'login':
            //require "$GLOBALS[root]/view/login.php";
            header ("Location: $GLOBALS[root]/view/login.php");
            break;


        case 'register':
            // require "$GLOBALS[root]/view/register.php";
            header ("Location: $GLOBALS[root]/view/register.php");
            break; 


        default:
            //require "$GLOBALS[root]/view/login.php";
            header ("Location: $GLOBALS[root]/view/login.php");
            break;
    }

    return;


?>
```

In the index.php in the switch-case-construct there are in each case commented out a require line and da header() line.

My problem:
If u use in all thre cases the requiere line then all works perfect.
But if i use the index.php as shown above (with header() instead of requiere) then nothing works. I get no error and the site is not even loaded...

Where is the problem?

Comment: Why did you switch back to using `header()`s anyway, when your last accepted answer gave you solid advise against that workaround? Also enable `error_reporting(E_ALL);` as usual / whenever something doesn't work.

Comment: You don't need the path delimiter str_replace (which ought to be strtr, if) also. Backslashes and forward slashes are functionally equivalent since DOS 2.0 and in this PHP context anyway. Also `__DIR__` is often a good substitute, as is `$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]` (in dbl quotes).

Comment: @ mario: error_reporting(E_ALL); shows me no errors (with header() the site is not even loading...). And i use header() because i want to set the URL correctly. And tanks for your tip from your second post, but this don't solve my problem.